# Preventing browser's page caching does not work for all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, browser-cache

I'm developing a rails application and I need to stop browser's page caching. 
I searched through all stackoverflow questions, blogs, and did Google search and I found that most people add the following lines of code to their application controller:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster

def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

I tried the same thing, but for me it works only on some pages, not on all of them. For instance when I log in, if I press the back button, a re-validation request is sent to my server and I prevent it, but when I log out and press the back button, it goes back to the previous page without re-validating. I tested this on Firefox and Chrome and the same thing happens in both browsers.

Here's what I do in my user controller when user presses the log out button:

```
def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to({:controller => 'homepage', :action => 'index'})
end
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: a random value at the end of the url might be work-around

Comment: I tried adding some random parameters at the end of the url, but still not working.

Comment: I used something like <a href="javascript:location='expense_list.html?ref='+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000 + Math.random()*1000000);"> in one of my previous web application and it worked